# Payoff of drawing card

Tags: probability, expectation, dynamic-programming

You have 100 cards with face value 1-100, randomly shuffled in a bag. Your payoff is the face value (in dollar) of the last card you draw. You can draw as many time as you want (with replacement), but each time you draw, it costs 1 dollar. What would be the best strategy to play this game? Does this game has a analytical solution?

Comment: Since you're drawing with replacement, your expected gain upon accepting the last card is always $(100×101)/2/100=50.5$ dollars, while it always costs one dollar to draw a _new_ card. You are best off just drawing one and accepting it; your expected gain is then 49.5 dollars.

Comment: A strategy that guarantees to win at least $50$ dollars: At draw #$k$, if you have a value of $51-k$ or more, then stop. Do not perform replacements of course.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel - not if you draw one on your first draw, it's hardly worth quitting with 1 dollar, when there is a 50% chance of exceeding $49

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: but it seems you get to look at the card you drew before you decide whether to draw again. If the card you draw is small enough you should clearly draw again.

Comment: @barakmanos:  that does not guarantee $50$.  You could continually draw small cards and never hit that value.

Comment: That was only my hunch. I welcome better solutions, like yours...

Comment: @barakmanos  Not following.  As drawing is "with replacement"  I might get the $1$ $100$ times in a row....so how can I guarantee a profit?

Comment: @lulu: I said, no replacement.

Comment: @barakmanos  Ah, got it.  Different problem.  But even so...I could get $\{1,2,\cdots\}$ in turn...so I get no profit.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Yes, you're right. I guess that I should think of some sort of refinement to this method (or abandon it completely, though I'm inclined to think that this should more or less be the general approach).

Comment: What you need though, is a strategy, or scheme, that maximises the expected return, it cannot ever guarantee a pay-off  - I think it's obvious that the expected return is > 50 with fairly simple strategies (like giving it 10 goes to try and exceed 50 for example)

Comment: @RossMillikan: Second thought - in the worse case scenario, you pick $1,2,3,\dots,100$ one by one in this order, leaving you with no profit at any stage of the game. So I think that there is no winning strategy here (at least not one which guarantees a profit of $n$ dollars with $100\%$ probability).

Comment: @lulu: Just saw your comment now. Looks identical to mine above :)

Comment: @barakmanos - The Q does not mention 'winning strategy' it mentions 'best' stategy - you want to expect the most money- here is a strategy - only accept 91 or more - you have a 65% chance of hitting that in the first 10 cards

Comment: I suspect there is an optimal minimum 'accept' value - it's always the same value, because the game never changes, it is an infinite game, other than each time you don't accept you are down a dollar

Comment: Without replacement you have something like the [Secretary Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem). I suspect with replacement should have a similar solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly you should draw the first card, as your expected profit is $49.5$.  After the first card, your strategy is to quit whenever you draw a card higher than $n$ and draw on $n$ or less.  The question is what $n$ should be.  Clearly it should be at least $49$.

Having chosen $n$, your average accepted card is $\frac {101+n}2$.  The chance of drawing an acceptable card is $\frac {100-n}{100}$.  The expected number of cards you will draw is

$1\left(\frac {100-n}{100}\right) +2\left(\frac {100-n}{100}\right)\left( \frac n{100}\right)+3\left(\frac {100-n}{100}\right)\left( \frac n{100}\right)^2+4\left(\frac {100-n}{100}\right)\left( \frac n{100}\right)^3+\ldots=\left(\frac {100-n}{100}\right) \left(1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1)\left(\frac k{100}\right)^k \right)=\left(\frac {100-n}{100}\right) \left( \frac 1{(1-\frac n{100})^2}\right)$

Our expected profit if we draw is then $$\frac {101+n}2-\left(\frac {100-n}{100}\right) \left( \frac 1{(1-\frac n{100})^2}\right)=\frac {101+n}2-\frac {100}{100-n}$$

[Searching for the maximum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20%20(101%2Bx)%2F2-(100-x)%2F100*(1%2B1%2F(1-x%2F100)%5E2)%20over%2050%20to%20100) finds it at $n=100-10\sqrt {2}\approx 85.8579$  As we must have $n$ an integer, we try $85$ and $86$, finding the maximum at $n=86$ with value $\frac {1209}{14} \approx 86.357$.  You should draw any time your card is $86$ or less.  As a sanity check, your average accepted card will be $93.5$ and it should take about $\frac {100}{14} \approx 7.14$ draws to get one, so the profit is reasonable.

An easier approach is to define $G(n)$ as the gain at $n$ andlook for the $n$ were $G(n+1)-G(n)$ turns negative.  This is $$G(n+1)-G(n)=\frac 12-\frac {100}{99-n}+\frac {100}{100-n}$$ which turns negative at about $n=85.349$, so we should increment from $n=85$ to $n=86$ but not further.

Comment: Congratulations. You've successfully elaborated on my initial stab at the question.

Answer (score 3):

Denote by $\xi$ the expected gain per game under optimal strategy. Then $\xi$ is a solution of the equation
$$x=\sum_{k=1}^{100}{1\over 100}\>\max\{k,x\}\ -1\ ,\tag{1}$$
because one will reject the first drawn number $k$ if continuing to draw seems more promising, and will accept $k$ otherwise. The function
$$f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^{100}{1\over 100}\>\max\{k,x\}\ -1$$
is increasing, continuous, and has derivative $f'(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor/100<1$ for noninteger $x$. Furthermore $f(0)=49.5>0$ and $f(100)=99<100$. It follows that $(1)$ has exactly one solution $\xi\in\>]0,100[\>$. Plotting $f$ shows that in fact $86<\xi<87$. We therefore write $\xi=86+\tau$ with $0<\tau<1$, and solve
$$86+\tau=\sum_{k=1}^{86}{86+\tau\over 100}+\sum_{k=87}^{100}{k\over 100}\ -1$$
for $\tau$. The result is $\tau={5\over14}$, so that $\xi=86.3571$.

The optimal strategy therefore turns out to be the following: Keep drawing until you get a number $\geq87$. The expected gain per game then is $86{5\over14}$.

Answer (score 0):

here's what my simulation got

[image]

https://dotnetfiddle.net/lie2h4

quit on 87 yields expected £86.532

quit on 85 yields expected £86.3432

quit on 86 yields expected £86.2902

quit on 88 yields expected £86.2602

quit on 89 yields expected £86.2053

quit on 84 yields expected £86.0106

quit on 83 yields expected £85.9269

quit on 90 yields expected £85.7383

quit on 82 yields expected £85.6761

quit on 91 yields expected £85.6596

quit on 81 yields expected £85.6201

quit on 80 yields expected £85.1205

quit on 79 yields expected £85.0571

quit on 92 yields expected £85.0558

.....

quit on 4 yields expected £51.0134

quit on 3 yields expected £50.1926

quit on 2 yields expected £50.1084

quit on 99 yields expected £49.7115

quit on 1 yields expected £49.6166

quit on 100 yields expected £1.1244

Comment: Perhaps you could display that in a graph. As it stands its very hard on the eye and screen.

Comment: I would also delete most of the lines of results, leaving only the top 5 or 10.

Comment: @ianmiller - good idea - is the sudden 'drop off' reasonable?

Comment: Looking at @RossMillikan's answer does suggest there is an asymptote at $n=100$.

Comment: @ RossMillikan - The bottom 10 seems the most interesting - with 100 seeming the worst attempt

Comment: @ianmiller - I think his answer is brilliant - but taking 100 as a decision value has to have a defined expectation, the loss is linear and the chances of the game going on decay negative exponentially - saying that his term is zero times infinity, so it probably does have a value

Comment: Then there is a problem here. [The limit](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B(101%2Bn)%2F2-(100-n)%2F100*(1%2B1%2F(1-n%2F100)%5E2),n-%3E100%5D) of @RossMillikan expression as $n\to100^+$ is negative infinity where as we should be expecting a finite (but small) amount.

Comment: @IanMiller:  as I defined it, you only stop when you draw higher than $n$, so if you take $n=100$ you will draw forever.  The expectation should be $-\infty$.  You should expect a finite answer if you take $n=99$, which you do.

Comment: Oh right. I had not thought correctly about the definition of $n$. When we substitute in $n=99$ we get an expected value of $-0.01$ which makes sense (and makes me wonder what is a fair price to play this game).